# What are the stages in a vegetable's lifecycle?

Tags: vegetables

What are the stages in a vegetable's lifecycle?

(Example: Seed to maturity to harvest)

Comment: You mean like seed, germination (root into soil, cotyledons pushed above), apical extension and presentation of true leaves, flowering & pollination, fruit set & seed generation, decline & death?

Comment: Yes something along those lines. I'm wondering if there is a scale or some defined stages. The BBCH seems to cover it but might be too thorough. I've thought that the stages might be something like: Seed, sprout, seedling, mid-season, and harvest are the main stages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good links is the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCH-scale and the link to the original document (it is long!).

The phenological development stages are different on different plants, but in general:

- seed
- cotyledon: usually one (monocots) or two (dicots) or many (conifers)
- leaves development (the green vegetables)
- building reserves (on biannual or perennials) on trunk or belowe ground, important for the *root vegetables*
- flowers
- fruit -> seed that will mature (low temperatures or water or digested by animals). Sometime the new plants grow directly in the flower and will be diffuse as a plant and not as seed (e.g. some garlic types).
- on perennials continuing to building reserves and then, when losing leaves, putting the reserves (amid) in trunk, roots, bulbs or tubers.
- on perennials continue the cycle on next grow season (starting with leaves or with flower according species). Some perennials will create again all parts above ground (garlic, onion, potato, asparagus), some plant will just continue to grow, with new branches (e.g. fruit plants, or pepper in warm climate)

But there is a huge variation, especially on vegetables, where we harvest different parts according the plant. The link on the wikipedia has the phases of the most important (economically) plant species. Ferns, mosses and lichens are totally different, but usually they are not grow as vegetables, but harvested in wild for medical uses.

Comment: Nice comment Giacomo!  Definitely one needs to address each different vegetable, your zone, your microclimate idiosyncrasies.  You aren't talking about 'scale' as a pest, right?  Just some sort of a chart?  Michael Dirr has an incredible book on vegetable gardening and then my other favorite is Shane Smith (don't worry about the green house thing, it is all pertinent and super graphs, etc.